# Creating multiple entities inside one document

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ravendb

Newbie, working with MVC and Document database. I have a Movies class

```
public class Movie
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string MovieName { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate{ get; set; }
    public int NumOfShows { get; set; }  
}
```

Right now I am creating documents in Raven DB, one for each movie. It looks like something like this. It gets updated from a MVC page. I am successfully able to do this now from MVC app to Raven.

```
{
   "MovieName": "Wild wild west",
   "ReleaseDate": "12th Dec",
   "NumOfShows ": "5"    
}
```

But this is not what my goal is. .. My objective is to create one document for one movieTheater with multiple movie informations in it. Something that looks like this...

```
 {
    "TheaterId": "Hd45",
    "TheaterName" : "Blvd",

    {
      "MovieName": "Wild wild west",
      "ReleaseDate": "12th Dec",
      "NumOfShows ": "5"    
    }
    {
      "MovieName": "Shrek",
      "ReleaseDate": "12th Dec",
      "NumOfShows ": "5"    
    }
    {
      "MovieName": "Ronin",
      "ReleaseDate": "12th Dec",
      "NumOfShows ": "5"    
    }
 }
```

How can I do this..Any help is greatly appreciated. Detailed explanation would be really helpful for my understanding.

**Update:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(TheaterViewModel input)
{
    var Theater = new Theater
    {
        TheaterId = input.Theater.TheaterId,
        TheaterName = input.Theater.TheaterName,
      // How do I get the Movies nested here, I mean updated 

    };
    _repository.Add(Theater);
    _repository.Save();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
public class MovieTheater
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Movie> MoviesOnShow { get; set; }
}

public class Movie
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public int NumOfShows { get; set; }
}
```

Here, `MovieTheater` will be your aggregate root, i.e. the part you load/save from database and work directly with.

Good luck!

Comment: Do both classes go into one model or separate models in the MVC structure.

Comment: These classes could represent your model. When you want to display this inside a view, you would typically map it to a specialized view model, and then present the view model instead. There is a library called AutoMapper that is being used for this purpose (mapping between model and view model).

Comment: Lidstrom: Please see comments above for an EDIT in the original post... How do I get the Movies data nested one by one as they are added in the code above..

Comment: You could have one action to create the theater. Then you could have another action to add movies to the theater. Does this make sense?

Comment: what happens when you update Movie? are you going to update all the different versions of that same document?

Comment: What document are you talking about? And what kind of update do you mean? `NumOfShows` or what?

Comment: is the Movie only ever going to show up once in one theatre? The Movie is _never_ going to be edited?

Comment: I don't know about the original requirements. But if the movies need to be edited, then the `MovieTheater` needs to embed a reference to the `Movie` document. It can also embed the movie name, if that is needed for some view. A little denormalization is OK within RavenDB, in fact it is probably expected.

Comment: @iwayneo : When a movie is updated, a theater has already been selected in a previous step. So a movie update is linked to a selected theater(s) only. If you update Shrek timings in Theater1, Shrek timings in Theater2 is not effected.

Comment: @Daniel Lidstrom: I think your comment about one action for theater and one action for movies to add in that theater makes sense. Right now I have two models (theater and movie) ..  , once a theater is added for the first time, it is there all the time.. next updates are going to be only movies..there should be a way to check of there is a theater document already in existence before a movie is updated..if not create one and add movies to it..can you throw more light on your last comment..

Comment: @ZVenue: You might be helped by reading some of the MvcMusicStore tutorial. It uses a similar model, although in that case the `MovieTheater` is a music store, and the `Movies` are music albums. You can find a relevant part of it here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-5. Actually, Ayende has written a good deal of posts on how to convert MvcMusicStore to use RavenDB: http://ayende.com/blog/search?q=mvcmusicstore. Specifically about the data model: http://ayende.com/blog/4506/porting-mvc-music-store-to-raven-the-data-model

Comment: this means the Movie document can exist within the same transactional boundary as the Theater document. The Movie might be it's own class but it doesn't need it's own Id

Comment: @iwayneo : Yes you can say that.

Comment: This is where I am struggling.. to come up with the correct viewmodel to work off this new structure...can you guys comment on that please. From a single page, i should be able to add movies to a theater document via a grid (create theater doc if there is no preexisting theater document )

Comment: i think you're over thinking it - it's more simple than you're making it. just run with it. have the movie as a part of the theater document. if it feels wrong, or you start having to do crazy stuff to make it work - rethink - but i think you have the right path now

Comment: @iwayneo : Probably because I am brand new to MVC and Document DBs.. I am clearly overthinking :-)

Comment: haha - run with it - when it gets awkward come back to SO and ask about it. right now i think you're thinking the right things :)

Comment: Sure, try it. If it doesn't work out, just ask another question :-)

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do this is to use DenormalizedReference:

[How would I model data that is heirarchal and relational in a document-oriented database system like RavenDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285711/how-would-i-model-data-that-is-heirarchal-and-relational-in-a-document-oriented-d/6289992#6289992)

Comment: Nice one, I didn't know this was possible.

Answer (score 0):

TheaterViewModel should have a collection of Movie in it like this:

```
Public List<Movie> Movies {get; set;}
```

Then in your Post action:

```
foreach(var movie in input.Movies)
{
//Additional code here...
}
```

Comment: But I am adding only one movie at a time.. why do I need to do a foreach?